# Accessing WebSphere API (Admin Console / Wsadmin)

Tags: websphere

Let's say I am writing a software that needs accesing to WebSphere API - retriving the cell name, the server names etc. - information I can get from the Admin Console - Is there a way (using http, web is perfered) to get the exact information I am looking for?

That is, an AdminConsole for programs to read?
I know that there is the wsadmin, but I don't know if it can be accessed as if it were a server. If so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, every functionality you see in the Admin console (or that can be accessed via wsadmin) is exposed by an MBean and can be invoked using JMX.

Answer (score 0):

1. wsadmin is a tool which is bundled with WAS and it allows everything you asked for. It can be used to administrate remote WAS, and it can be run as standalone program without WAS.
2. WAS has JMX interface for managed beans. Through it you can inspect configuration and administrate all AdminControl options given by wasdmin and even more.